# Certain keys on my keyboard stopped working (not even in an external keyboard)

Tags: keyboard

On my laptop the keys (`ASDFGJKL;' ENTER`, the entire home row) aren't working.

The laptop is 6 years old and I never spilled anything on my keyboard. Could there be a errorneous setting in BIOS?

Comment: If you aren't afraid to get inside your laptop, I'd suggest yo to unplug your laptop's keyboard, connect an external one and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this It may solve your problem. As you are telling that it is not working on external key board also otherwise you have to change you'r key board.

1. Turn off your laptop  and remove the battery.
2. Now press and hold the power button for 10 to 15 sec.
3. Then start you'r laptop by connecting to charger without battery.
4. Test the key board and install the battery.

It sometimes happen because of static charge.

Answer (score 0):

No, that isn't due to anything in the BIOS, it will be a hardware fault.

Most likely due to a poor connection to that row. I'm afraid that you will need to get someone to replace the keyboard.